# google analytics reports with the primary dimension is the time zone of the visitor

Tags: google-analytics, report

Is it possible to generate Google Analytics (out of the box) reports where the primary dimension is the time zone of the visitor instead of the region for example, and without use of custom variables.

Thanks

Comment: You can't do that out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!